# Nuclear cusp condition

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

Does the nuclear cusp condition
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial r_\alpha} \bar{\rho}(r_\alpha) \vert_{r_\alpha = 0} = -2 Z_\alpha \bar{\rho}(0)
$$
hold only for the ground state of a quantum mechanical system?
See the [Wikipedia Electron density page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_density).

Comment: For a single-electron bound eigenstate it holds for any $n$ and $\ell$ (with $\ell>0$ case being trivial). Just look at the hydrogenic eigenfunctions. Dunno though, how to prove this for a multi-electron system.